# Cannot sort list of items with float using lambda. What do?

Tags: python, spss

I have a list of items containing a list of lists, like:

```
lst=
['0038b49c491bb67c9459318c2afce65f        ', 13653705600.0, 13657075200.0]
['0038bad168c0358a65f56ce04ebb0bfa        ', 13724726400.0, 13728441600.0]
['0038e2c5f01fedfa0b4025699374c2a4        ', 13709952000.0, 13723948800.0]
['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af        ', 13468204800.0, 13471142400.0]
['0038eb7855072fd017250641fe8ab98b        ', 13700448000.0, 13700448000.0]
['0038eb982de28f0372dbb5c9a76b8db0        ', 13526784000.0, 13526784000.0]
['0038edbe1afe7308d21eb3657952b6e7        ', 13475548800.0, 13476758400.0]
```

i'm trying to create a copy of this list which sorts by the first item, then the second item.

I've been doing research and have tried:
lst2=sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])

To which i get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I've also tried itemgetter, which gets me the same error.

Here's the code - it's intended to be an SPSS function which creates a variable based upon a hierarchy of dates.

```
def rcnv():
    
        index=spssaux.VariableDict().VariableIndex
        v_idx=[index(v) for v in varlist]
        
        vals = [None] * len(v_idx)
        row_to_all=[]
        for i,v in enumerate(v_idx):
            row_to_all.append(i)
        
        cur=spss.Cursor(var=v_idx, accessType='w')
        #cvtDates="ALL"
        for i in range(cur.GetCaseCount()):
            row=cur.fetchone()
            for i,v in enumerate(row):
                j=row_to_all[i]
                vals[j]=v
            
              
            (CaseID, Dispo,Prosecuted, Cnvctd, Violent, Dt1, Dt2, Dt3, Dt4) = vals
    
            lst=[]
            lst.append(CaseID)

            
            if Prosecuted== 1 and CaseDisposition== 2:  
                repeat(lst, Dt1, Dt2, Dt3,Dt)
            elif Prosecuted== 1:  
                repeat(lst, Dt1, Dt2, Dt3,Dt4)
            elif Prosecuted== 0:  
                repeat(lst, Dt1, Dt2, Dt3,Dt4)
            else:  
                repeat(lst, Dt1, Dt2, Dt3,Dt4)
                  
            print(lst)
            lst2=sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
            
                          
rcnv()
```

Comment: Your `lst` assignment statement is not legal Python.
Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
Until we have the MRE, we'd just be guessing on the structure of `lst` and the effect of your sort key.

Comment: To expand on @Prune, you're missing a set of [...] around the list definition as what you (presumably) want is a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just use this:

```
my_list = sorted(lst)
```

Sorted will use the order to sort (it will first try to sort on item 1 of each list, then om item 2).

A working example:

```
lst =[["a", 2], ["a", 1], ["c", 1], ["b",2]]
# expect this to be sorted in (index) order 1,0,3,2
print(sorted(lst))
# > [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
#        1         0         3         2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your input "list" so that it is a valid Python structure, then you can sort in any number of dimensions with this general approach:

```
lst= [
['0038b49c491bb67c9459318c2afce65f        ', 13653705600.0, 13657075200.0],
['0038bad168c0358a65f56ce04ebb0bfa        ', 13724726400.0, 13728441600.0],
['0038e2c5f01fedfa0b4025699374c2a4        ', 13709952000.0, 13723948800.0],
['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af        ', 33.0, 13471142400.0],
['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af        ', 66.0, 13471142400.0],
['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af        ', 55.0, 13471142400.0],
['0038eb7855072fd017250641fe8ab98b        ', 13700448000.0, 13700448000.0],
['0038eb982de28f0372dbb5c9a76b8db0        ', 13526784000.0, 13526784000.0],
['0038edbe1afe7308d21eb3657952b6e7        ', 13475548800.0, 13476758400.0]]

lst2=sorted(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[0])

print(lst2)
```

Result:

> [['0038b49c491bb67c9459318c2afce65f        ', 13653705600.0,
> 13657075200.0], ['0038bad168c0358a65f56ce04ebb0bfa        ', 13724726400.0, 13728441600.0], ['0038e2c5f01fedfa0b4025699374c2a4        ', 13709952000.0, 13723948800.0], ['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af
> ', 33.0, 13471142400.0], ['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af        ',
> 55.0, 13471142400.0], ['0038e75eee2104045dfe323a3097e7af        ', 66.0, 13471142400.0], ['0038eb7855072fd017250641fe8ab98b        ', 13700448000.0, 13700448000.0], ['0038eb982de28f0372dbb5c9a76b8db0        ', 13526784000.0, 13526784000.0], ['0038edbe1afe7308d21eb3657952b6e7
> ', 13475548800.0, 13476758400.0]]

So you were on the right track with your call to `sorted`.  There was nothing wrong with it...it just didn't go far enough.
This first sorts on the second column, and then sorts again on the first column.  This gives you the two level sort you want because `sorted` is guaranteed to perform a "stable sort", which means that any items that have the same key for the purposes of the sort retain their relative order in the resulting list.

The above approach would work if you wanted to sort on the columns in the other order...you'd just swap the indexes `0` and `1`.  It turns out that because you want to search on each field in the order they appear in the items of your input list, you can just do this:

```
lst2=sorted(lst)
```

and get the same results. Just keep in mind that this only works if the columns happen to be in the right order to give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your lst is not defined correctly. You are missing a `[` and `]`.

To address your sort question, see below....

Looks like you want to sort to sort the columns one by one within the list.

You don't need to give the key as sorted uses the default column by column sort.

However, if you did want to specify the option to only sort by 2nd and 3rd columnn, you can specify x[1:] to pick the 2nd and 3rd column in a 3 column list.

Here's an example of both:

```
lst = [['m',7,13.5],['k',9,10.25],['d',12,11.5],
       ['k',8,11.5],['d',8,12.5],['m',8,10.5],
       ['m',7,12.5],['k',9,8.5],['d',8,10.5]]

for a in lst:print (a)

lst1 = sorted(lst)
print (lst1)
```

Before:

```
['m', 7, 13.5]
['k', 9, 10.25]
['d', 12, 11.5]
['k', 8, 11.5]
['d', 8, 12.5]
['m', 8, 10.5]
['m', 7, 12.5]
['k', 9, 8.5]
['d', 8, 10.5]
```

After sort:

```
['d', 8, 10.5]
['d', 8, 12.5]
['d', 12, 11.5]
['k', 8, 11.5]
['k', 9, 8.5]
['k', 9, 10.25]
['m', 7, 12.5]
['m', 7, 13.5]
['m', 8, 10.5]
```

If you were to look for it to sort by 2nd and 3rd column, then here's the code and results.

```
lst1 = sorted(lst,key=lambda x: x[1:])
```

Before Sort:

```
['m', 7, 13.5]
['k', 9, 10.25]
['d', 12, 11.5]
['k', 8, 11.5]
['d', 8, 12.5]
['m', 8, 10.5]
['m', 7, 12.5]
['k', 9, 8.5]
['d', 8, 10.5]
```

After Sort:

```
['m', 7, 12.5]
['m', 7, 13.5]
['m', 8, 10.5]
['d', 8, 10.5]
['k', 8, 11.5]
['d', 8, 12.5]
['k', 9, 8.5]
['k', 9, 10.25]
['d', 12, 11.5]
```